# Angularjs, How to destroy partials even using back button from browser?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have A,B,C partials in angular. I start using page A then B , and from B to C. Staying at C, I want to destroy A, B, C partials (maybe using a logout function or similar) so if I want to return using back button to B or keeping pressing back button to navigate directly to A, How I could control this situation and do something else? (for example redirect to another page).

Someone knows how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have a controller for each partial then you can use $destroy, this event is triggred by angular whenever the controllers scope is destroyed

> $destroy()
>
> Removes the current scope (and all of its children) from the parent
>   scope. Removal implies that calls to $digest() will no longer
>   propagate to the current scope and its children. Removal also implies
>   that the current scope is eligible for garbage collection.
>
> The $destroy() is usually used by directives such as ngRepeat for
>   managing the unrolling of the loop.
>
> Just before a scope is destroyed a $destroy event is broadcasted on
>   this scope. Application code can register a $destroy event handler
>   that will give it chance to perform any necessary cleanup.

below is an example on how to use it

```
ctrl.directive('handleDestroy', function() {
    return function(scope, tElement, attributes) {        
        scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
            alert("In destroy of:" + scope.todo.text);
        });
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the $router has `$routeChangeStarted` event, that you can subscribe to. This would look something like

```
 $scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, nextLoc, currentLoc) {
        //Add your custom logic based on nextloc and currentloc to change location using the $location service
    });
```

Comment: Thanks @Chandermani, I tried this before, but doest not work at 100%. In my use case using back button , currentLoc is undefined but also when use refresh button, I have not yet found a way to distinguish both events using currentLoc ,nextLoc or event. The point is how to detect on $routeChangeStart that the session was finished (or partials were destroyed)?